# variable incremented inside function has value 1

Tags: php, scope

EDIT: so sorry, the original code was an iteration while i was trying to figure the problem out, I've edited the code
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096564/php-increment-a-variable-in-a-function-the-function-runs-in-a-forloop-resets-t) question started similar, but here's the real problem I'm having:

In this code:

```
<?php
    $a = 2:

    function incr(){
        $a++;
    echo $a;
    }

    echo $a;
    incr();
?>
```

the output is 2  and  then 1, and  that signals to me that the variable `$a` gets initialized to 0 inside the function. Does the server know just by the virtue that i used the increment syntax to initialize the variable to 0?

Comment: your problem is that `$a` is not in scope inside of your function. inside of the function, `$a` is not defined

Comment: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Giving my function access to outside variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531221/giving-my-function-access-to-outside-variable)

Comment: It's interesting you got 1 out of the echo incr(); call.  Within incr, $a is undefined.  So, $a++ is undefined and you shouldn't get any output.  Is this a simplification of a problem, or are you actually seeing that output?  Stick it into http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and only 2 is output.

Comment: @Barbara undefined variables are only a notice, and doing (basically) `null + 1` will coerce the null value to an integer type, apparently the value `0` prior to attempting the addition. See the manual on [type juggling](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). You can configure php so that notices are treated like errors, but by default they are not.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird thanks for the heads up, that made me realize that i pasted the wrong code block in. Fixed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$a` is undefined, then when you increment it, it goes to `1`.

```
function incr(){
    $a++; // $a is undefined
    return $a;
}
```

As pointed out in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

> Note:
>
> The increment/decrement operators only affect numbers and strings. Arrays, objects and resources are not affected. **Decrementing NULL values has no effect too, but incrementing them results in 1.**

You could use `global`, and it will return as expected.

```
function incr(){
    global $a;
    $a++;
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: ah yes this is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be properly incremented within the function, you need to change your code to this:

```
<?php
    $a = 2:

    function incr($a){
        return $a++;
    }

    echo $a;
    echo incr($a);
?>
```

The $a inside and the $a outside the function are two entirely different variables in your code snippet, they are not in the same **scope**.

You can read about variable scope here : http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

You can also use global variables, also mentioned in the previous link, however their use is usually not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
<?php
    $a = 2:

    function incr($a){
        return $a++;
    }

    echo $a;
    echo incr($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In php global variables have to be declared global inside the function it is using them:

```
<?php
    $a = 2:

    function incr(){
        global $a;
        $a++;
    }

    echo $a;
    incr();
    echo $a;
?>
```

Don't mean to be rude, but this is explained in the manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Or pass them as variables as the other answers by suggest. Note that PHP also allows to pass variables by reference (at least in PHP 5).